# Polymer2.0 - Trying to change webcomponent attribute value by binding value from paper-input

Tags: web-component, polymer-2.0

I am trying to control the attribute value of webcomponent from polymer paper input.

I am able to change values with two binding of paper input but not able to control the attribute value

I created below example and trying to change resizable-panels attribute to vertical

```
 <resizable-panels [[text]]>
```

to

```
 <resizable-panels vertical>
```

using paper-input

Codepen code for reference
https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/QMjjQw

HTML:

```
  <head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+v2.0.0/shadycss+webcomponents+1.0.0/components/">
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="resizable-panels/resizable-panels.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html" 
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
<style>
.panel { padding: 20px; color: white; font-family: sans-serif; width: 50%; }
      .p1 { background-color: #673AB7; }
      .p2 { background-color: #E91E63; }
      .p3 { background-color: #00BCD4; }
      .p4 { background-color: #FB8C00; }
      .p5 { background-color: #607D8B; }
      .p6 { background-color: #4CAF50; }
</style>
   <paper-input value="{{text::input}}"></paper-input>   
  <resizable-panels id="rp-2">
      <div class="panel p1">Lorem ipsum dolor…</div>
      <div class="panel p2">Second panel</div>
    </resizable-panels>
      <br>
         <resizable-panels [[text]]>
      <div class="panel p1">Lorem ipsum dolor…</div>
      <div class="panel p1">Second panel</div>
      <div class="panel p1">Third panel</div>
    </resizable-panels>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

JS:

```
  class XFoo extends Polymer.Element {
    static get is() { return 'x-foo'; }

    static get properties() {
      return {};

    }
       toggle() {
  this.$.collapse.toggle();
}

  }
  customElements.define(XFoo.is, XFoo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats not how its supposed to work, you cant just slap a tag like  and expect this to work - since this is not server side building - you are not supposed to treat your templates like this.

Here is a working demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzOgQX

You should be toggling a boolean property `vertical` between true/false to archieve what you want. Hope this helps.